# jquery Post does not work in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I just copied some code from an asp.net mvc 2 app which works. Now i am trying it in asp.net mvc 3 and it does not call the save method on the controller?

controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult save(string inputdata)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = string.Format("From the controller - you have clicked the GO-button ! ") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

view:

```
<button id="but">go</button>
<div id=result></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(

    $("#but").click(
        function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/save",
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                data: "test",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#result").html(result.Result);
                }
            });

        }
    )

    );

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the data correctly. The action argument is called `inputdata`. So you should use this same name in the `data` hash of the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/save',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { inputdata: 'test' },
    success: function (result) {
        $('#result').html(result.Result);
    }
});
```

Also never hardcode urls in your javascript, always use url helpers or your application will simply stop working when you deploy due to the possibility of having a virtual directory name:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("save", "home")',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { inputdata: 'test' },
    success: function (result) {
        $('#result').html(result.Result);
    }
});
```

Another issue that you have with your code is that you are not canceling the default action of the button meaning that if this is an action link or a submit button the AJAX request might never have the time to execute before the browser redirects.

Also you don't need to specify the `dataType` to JSON as jQuery is intelligent enough to deduce this from the Content-Type response header sent from the server.

So the final version should look something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#but').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("save", "home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { inputdata: 'test' },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result').html(result.Result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```